# Spring Security : difference between ROLE_ANONYMOUS and IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY

Tags: spring-security

In Spring Security What's difference between ROLE_ANONYMOUS and IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY .

In other words ,  how are RoleVoter and AuthenticatedVoter different ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the relevant section in [spring security documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/anonymous.html),

> You will often see the ROLE_ANONYMOUS
>   attribute in the above interceptor
>   configuration replaced with
>   IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, which is
>   effectively the same thing when
>   defining access controls. This is an
>   example of the use of the
>   AuthenticatedVoter which we will see
>   in the authorization chapter. It uses
>   an AuthenticationTrustResolver to
>   process this particular configuration
>   attribute and grant access to
>   anonymous users. The
>   AuthenticatedVoter approach is more
>   powerful, since it allows you to
>   differentiate between anonymous,
>   remember-me and fully-authenticated
>   users. If you don't need this
>   functionality though, then you can
>   stick with ROLE_ANONYMOUS, which will
>   be processed by Spring Security's
>   standard RoleVoter.

Also, from Luke's comment on the related [jira issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1322?focusedCommentId=49284&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-49284),

> The anonymous access issue is partly
>   historical. Anonymous tokens were
>   introduced initially (i.e.
>   ROLE_ANONYMOUS) which would allow you
>   to use a "secure-by-defaul"
>   configurations with specific
>   exceptions. At a later stage the
>   AuthenticatedVoter was introduced to
>   allow you to differentiate between
>   different levels of authentication -
>   anonyous, remember-me and
>   fully-authenticated (i.e. logged in
>   during the current session). I've
>   added an extra bit to the anonymous
>   chapter to explain that they are the
>   same unless you require the extra
>   functionality offered by the
>   AuthenticatedVoter.